# Memory Errors in Python

Tags: python, numpy, memory, matrix, bigdata

I created a non-sparse matrix in Python with the shape 156.100.000 x 513 and therefore 8.007.930.000 entries. The entries are float32 numbers. I obviously have troubles now using the data within my 8GB RAM system.

What are common approaches to address this problem? I'm not sure how to use the data e.g. chunk-wise since all those Numpy and Scipy functions always operate on the whole dataset. Sparse matrices won't work because of the data structure and I also have troubles to understand if HDF5 is really suited towards my problem (which is **use a big dataset with standard Numpy-functions without crashing my memory**)

Comment: If you start using large sparse matrices, you have to restrict yourself to operations that work on sparse matrices. Converting such a large matrix to a dense matrix is not possible anymore on consumer machines.

Comment: I'm talking about non-sparse matrices.

Comment: Oh, then: get access to a machine with a LOT of ram - most algorithms only work effectively if all the data is in RAM. So the algorithms are designed accordingly. AFAIK you cannot use scipy/numpy for data that does not fit into ram

Comment: It's hard to offer any specific advice without knowing what you want to do with the data. One option would be to use a memory-mapped array ([`np.memmap`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html)). These are similar to standard numpy arrays (many numpy functions will accept an `np.memmap` array in place of an `np.ndarray`), except the data will be stored in a file on disk, with a read/write cache that is held in RAM and managed by the OS. If you can operate on smaller chunks of the whole array then you could also use HDF5 (e.g. h5py or PyTables).

Comment: You could also look into [`bcolz`](http://bcolz.blosc.org/intro.html), which offers a numpy array-like container with either on-disk or in-memory compression. However it currently only supports a limited subset of numpy features.